# Are there dialects where "would have" is used to describe a factual event long in the past?

Tags: american-english, dialects, would-have-been

I've recently noticed that a few people I know, all native American English speakers in their 50s-70s and originally from the Midwest, use "would have" and related forms when talking about factual events that happened relatively long ago.

Here's a made-up example of what I mean:

Upon seeing George Washington's house, one might say "This is where Washington *would have* lived." instead of "This is where Washington lived."

Another example: "I *would've* been born in that hospital." as equivalent to "I was born in that hospital."

This sentence, however, isn't an example: "I would have had lunch with her every day last week." It doesn't work because it's insufficiently far in the past.

As @Cascabel notes, it's better to have real examples than made-up ones. So, I hopped on the phone and asked one of the "would have" users a history question (he's a baseball historian) without mentioning my goal. Sure enough, here are a few non-made-up examples:

- "He would've been there from 1941-1963, excluding a brief period he took off for the war."
- "My father would've taken me to see him for my tenth and eleventh birthdays."
- "It wouldn't have been uncommon for baseball players to have had second jobs back then - it certainly wasn't like today."

Is this a regionalism? A generationally-related usage? Or is it some other phenomenon I don't know the name of? I've only seen a handful of people do this, so, for all I know, they're the only ones.

Is there a name for this sort of usage? I'm not quite sure what to call it, which has made searching for it somewhat difficult, and it's very possible that I've missed an already existing answer.

Comment: Possibly you are hearing usages of "would" used like "used to" to describe past habitual actions. It would be a good idea to listen carefully the next time you hear this and note down an actual example, rather than making up free examples that may not pattern the usage.

Comment: Take, for example, [*As a good Jew, Jesus would have grown up within a theological model.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22As+a+good+Jew%2C+Jesus+would+have+grown+up+within+a+theological+model.%22) There's no suggestion that Jesus might *not* have been a good Jew, or that anything "habitual" is being referenced. This isn't the same usage as, say, *I would have thought Jesus grew up within a theological model*, where the difference between *I think* and *I would have thought* is that the latter is slightly more "circumspect, hesitant, self-effacing, deferential" (almost a "hedge").

Comment: interesting.  i would take your example as a rearrangement of "that would be where George Washington lived."  midwestern politeness, maybe?

Comment: @Cascabel +10. But sadly impossible to award.

Comment: I have heard this in use and I have always explained it to myself like this.  The full sentence would be something like:  If you had visited here in the 1780’s this is where George Washington would have lived.

Comment: @Cascabel Good thought, though I don't think there's any element of habituality in a lot of these. You're right that real-life examples are better than made-up ones, so I called up one of these speakers and wrote down everything he said, without mentioning the "would have" thing, and I've updated the question with a couple of real examples.

Comment: It is common to use this when you aren't stating a direct fact so much as reasoning something out. It seems to be a subjunctive use expressing an "opinion" in the sense you didn't see it for yourself - the info being second hand, deduced, or the specifics are fuzzy. "That would have been about ..." and "that would have been around ..." are common idiomatic phrases along the same lines.

Comment: Nice notice of this phenomenon. When reading it, it sounds crazy to think people are so ... conditional about reporting a fact. But then saying this aloud I realize I do it and I mean it factually. On introspection it feels like a bit of polite softening, trying not to be so blunt about facts.

Comment: What @Jim said, or like *This is where GW  would have slept, if you had been here to see him*.

Comment: I have just seen real-life examples in the cathedral ruins if St. Andrews, Scotland.
"North Nave Aisle. This **would have been** sub-divided to contain a number of altars."

"The rood screen **would have been** here. In front of it were placed the principal altar or altars of the lay folk who worshipped in the cathedral."

What I would expect is just the plain "would", like:

"This would be sub-divided..." = this used to be sub-divided.

The rood screen would be here." = the rood screen used to be here.

I expect they pretty well know what was there.

Answer (score 1):

No opinion about George Washington.  But for the baseball historian, it's simple.  He is speculating, trying to reconstruct a timeline and arrangement of facts in his timeline.

If he doesn't have specific documentation to back up certain facts and dates, then he has to do some thinking to figure out what happened when, and he expresses that with "would have."

Comment: I don't think he's speculating - at least, not entirely. He had, at the time of answering, the year information in front of him, and I'm not sure the Washington example is separable. I'll see about getting more examples of actual usage to test whether or not that Washington example is accurate.

Comment: @Tutleman - If he has made himself a timeline or a chart to refer back to during the conversation/interview, then he can say "was."  Otherwise, if he's in any doubt at all, he can say "would have been."  I'm just describing the expression as I've heard it used and as I have used it.  My guess is that today's 30YOs will speak that way in 20 years too.

Comment: Totally fair. This explanation *does* make sense with a lot of aspects of what I've heard, though "Washington-style" usages are still up in the air, and barring an explanation that can handle those, too, I'll have no qualms accepting this answer.

Comment: @Tutleman - Yeah, the Washington thing has me stumped.

Comment: We can't tell from the given contexts of the sentences that the speaker is "speculating." And that is not the only scenario that licenses the use of *would have*.

Comment: @Clare - That sounds intriguing.  Care to write an answer about the other scenario(s)?

Answer (score 1):

We use "would have" when we speculate about something that probably happened, in the past, and will explain something else.

Example: somebody doesn't arrive who should have by now. We say: "He would have run into a problem that delayed him".

Answer (score -2):

Being in the age group and having lived originally in Midwest it seems to me that  "would have" used in the "long ago" past comes into use mostly when there is a negative or lack of action mentioned as the premise of that past existing situation.

Example:

"Her mother didn't bring along a coat, or she would have been wearing it, since Minneapolis was so cold that year in early October."